# Writing test case using Sinon NodeJs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I was writing unit test case for some nested function while using third part library (Kafkajs). The test case is first create an object and then calling a class object inside it and then calling a function from that class. This complete code is inside third party SDK.

I had a below code like this

KafkaWrapper.ts

```
export class KafkaWrapper {
  kafkaInstance: any;

  constructor() {
    this.kafkaInstance = new Kafka({
      clientId: Config.serviceSettings.serviceTag,
      brokers: [Config.kafkaBrokers!],
      logLevel: logLevel.ERROR,
      logCreator: CustomLogCreator,
    });
  }
}
```

and then I have another kafka-consumer.ts file which is consume above class like

```
const kafkaEvent = new KafkaWrapper();
const consumer = kafkaEvent.kafkaInstance.consumer({ groupId: Config.cdnPurgeConsumerGroup });
export default class CDNPurgeJobConsumer {
  public static async brokerConnection(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Broker connection');
    await consumer.connect();
  }
}
```

The test case that I wrote till now is

```
  it('create fake connection with kafka broker', async function () {
    const stub = sandbox.stub(Kafka, 'consumer').returns({
      connect: sinon.fake()
    });
    await CDNPurgeJobConsumer.brokerConnection();
    expect(stub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    stub.restore();
  });
```

I also tried to fake the KafkaWrapper function but it also didn't worked for me.

Here I want to mock connect function since `Kafka` class is from third party library.
The third party library name is kafkajs and version is 1.15.0.

I have tried to stub and sky on `Kafka` but it is failing everytime.

Comment: Could you share what unit test were you able to write unitl now? Although its failing?

Comment: Updated the post description with the test case that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

@Techno Crazzyyyy What you can do here is

```
spyOn(KafkaWrapper.prototype, "kafkaInstance").and.returnValue({
                consumer: function () {
                    return {
                        connect: function () {
                            return Promise.resolve({})
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Although I am using jasmine here, this should help you to spy your dependencies here.

Comment: @techno-crazzyyyy let me know if you face any issue, or you expect any improvement.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look on this. After implementing this I am getting this error `Attempted to wrap undefined property kafkaInstance as function` kafkaInstance is a variable inside KafkaWrapper class.

Comment: I also tried     
const stub = sandbox.stub(KafkaWrapper.prototype, 'kafkaInstance').get(() => {
      return {
        consumer: function () {
          return {
            connect: async function () {
              Promise.resolve({});
            },
          };
        },
      };
    });

But it is also giving me `Cannot stub non-existent property kafkaInstance`

Comment: Okay, let me check once..

Comment: This solution works fine with I declare `kafkaEvent` and `consumer` inside the `brokerConnection` function, but I need to mock the code the way it is described